# Simple multiplication program fix

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this program, I want to keep asking the user for a number until they press 0. When they press 0, all the numbers they inputted should get multiplied. However, when I run this program it does not evaluate the correct output.

```
numbers = []
product = 1
inputNumberOne = input("Please enter a number")
numbers.append(inputNumberOne)
while True:

    if inputNumberOne.isnumeric():
        numbers.append(inputNumberOne)
        inputNumberTwo = input("What number do you want to multiply with?")
        if inputNumberTwo.isnumeric() and inputNumberTwo != '0':
            numbers.append(inputNumberTwo)
        elif inputNumberTwo == '0':
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid input.")
    else:
        print("That's not an a valid integer.")

for i in range(0, len(numbers)):
    numbers[i] = int(numbers[i])

for num in numbers:
    product = int(product) * int(num)
    
print(f"The final product is {product}")
```

Comment: You can use only one `inputNumber` variable, moving all the logic inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be ok:

```
def get_valid_num(line):
    next_num = input(line)
    if next_num.isnumeric():
        return int(next_num)
    else:
        print("Invalid Input! Try again:")
        return get_valid_num(line)

total = 0
while True:
    if total == 0:
        next_num = get_valid_num("Please enter a number")
        #if next_num == 0: break
        total = next_num
    else: 
        next_num = get_valid_num("What number do you want to multiply it with?")
        if next_num == 0: break
        total *= next_num

print('final product is', total)
```

if the very first input can be 0 you have to uncomment that one line.